# Auto size input field

Tags: css, input, styling

Im working on a header which uses bootstrap. In the header there is a logo, search box and 2  styled buttons. The problem i am having is that on a big resolution screen the search box is fine and displays in the space between the logo and the buttons.
However, if i go to a small screen then the display goes all weird and out of line.
My question is how can i make the textbox autosize accroding to the resolution?
 does not work

Website: http://verifiedfeedback.com/

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: still, this moves the other elements out of place :/ *sigh*

Comment: It doesn't relevant, but great desing!

Comment: it is relavent for users to search for companies to review... please this is one thing i am stuck on

Comment: try to wrap the #topNavigation  elements to `display: table-cell`

Comment: nope, still no luck but thanks for help guys * sigh * need to work this out soon

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries([example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/how-to-create-media-queries-in-responsive-web-design/1789)) to edit certain elements for different screen sizes, I suggest to at least remove the margin left on your search box when a smaller screen resolution is used. Also for example on really small screen resolutions you could remove the `float: right` on your `.nav-pull-right`